# if $(|a\rangle - |b\rangle)\langle b| + |b\rangle(\langle a| - \langle b|) = 0$ then $|a\rangle = |b\rangle$, where $|a\rangle, |b\rangle$ unit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Essentially the problem above. I've tried approaching it by arguing that $|b\rangle(\langle a| - \langle b|)$ is the adjoint of $(|a\rangle - |b\rangle)\langle b|$, and since $|b\rangle$ nonzero, since unitary, then it must be such that $|a\rangle-|b\rangle = 0$, except, I can't quite formalise that argument, since I cannot factorise it out.

What steps am I missing?

Alternatively, how can it be shown?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I think you mean that $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), not that they are "[unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix)".

Comment: As a hint, define an operator $A = |a\rangle \langle b | + |b\rangle\langle a| - 2|b\rangle\langle b|$. You are assuming that $A=0$. Compute and simplify $A|a\rangle$ and $A|b\rangle$, from which you should be able to verify that $|\langle a|b\rangle|^2 = 1$. Hence $|a\rangle = \lambda |b\rangle$ for some complex number $\lambda$ with unit modulus. Plug this into $A$ to conclude that $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: @MarkGirard Thank you! That worked!